# Convexity of manifold?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be complete Riemannian manifolds and we consider the Riemannian manifold of multiplication $M\times N$ with the metric $g_{M\times N} =g_M + g_ N $. A subset $A$ of $M\times N$ is said to be convex if the geodesic connecting of two arbitrary points in $A$ is completely in $A$. My problem is:

> Is $M$ a convex set in $M\times N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A curve $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ is a geodesic in $M=M_1\times M_2$ if and only if $\alpha_i$ is a geodesic in $M_i$ for each $i$. Thus using your definition, the sets $\{p\}\times M_2$ and $M_1 \times \{q\}$ are convex subsets of $M_1\times M_2$